# bash / zsh script behaviour difference

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a simple script:

```
is_prime () {
    local factors
    factors=( $( factor "$1" | cut -d ':' -f 2 ) )
    [ ${#factors} -le 1 ]
}

starting () {
    for i in $(seq 10 99); do
        if is_prime "$i" ; then echo "$i" ; fi
    done
}


starting
```

If I run it with `/bin/zsh`, it prints all the primes between 10 and 99, as I would expect. If I run it with `/bin/bash`, however, it does the exact *opposite*: it prints all non-prime values in that range! I understand `zsh`s behaviour, but why does bash do what it does? Is the behaviour of `test` different in some relevant way?

Comment: BTW, consider `for ((i=10; i<99; i++))` instead of `for i in $(seq ...)`; this keeps evaluation internal to the shell rather than launching a nonstandardized external tool. (I've actually seen someone build an implementation of `seq` that spelled out numbers just to mess with people -- `one`, `two`, etc; there's no POSIX standard for it, so it's perfectly legal for it to do weird things, or simply not be there at all).

Comment: You could also get rid of `cut`: `factor_str=$(factor "$1"); factor_str=${factor_str#*:}; read -A factors <<<"$factor_str"` (in zsh), or `read -a factors <<<"$factor_str"` (in bash). Frankly, they're different enough shells that it assuming that things will work between them isn't a great habit to be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently in `zsh` this `${#factors}` expansion on an array gets you the length of the array. It doesn't do that in `bash`. In `bash` that gets you the length of the first element of the array.

Compare these outputs:

```
$ zsh -c 'foo=(a b c); echo $foo'
a b c
$ bash -c 'foo=(a b c); echo $foo'
a
$ zsh -c 'foo=(a b c); echo ${#foo}'
3
$ bash -c 'foo=(a b c); echo ${#foo}'
1
```

So that's why your script is going wrong for `bash`. To get the value you expected there you need to use `${#factors[@]}` (which also works in `zsh`).

```
$ zsh -c 'foo=(a b c); echo ${#foo[@]}'
3
$ bash -c 'foo=(a b c); echo ${#foo[@]}'
3
```

Comment: `set -x` is a very useful tool. =)

Comment: Aha! And because all non-prime numbers less than 100 have a single-digit factor, it was just a funny accident that bash was printing all and only the composite numbers! Thanks